# Summation of time complexity for a diminishing for loop with logarithmic runtime.

Tags: summation, algorithms, asymptotics

I trying to determine the time complexity of this diminishing for-loop by calculating how many times it is executed using **summations**.

##### How many times does this loop run?

```
for(int i = n; i >= 1; i = i/2) {
 // Does something in O(1)
}
```

My basic understanding is that `i` in this loop will diminish as follows:
$\frac{n}{2^0}$, $\frac{n}{2^1}$, $\frac{n}{2^1}$, ... , $\frac{n}{2^k}$ $\text{until}$ $\frac{n}{2^k}$ = 1. Leading to $k=\log_2(n).$

How do i put this into a summation expression that leads to the time complexity $T(n)$?

Trying to describe this progression using summations I get the following:
$$
 T(n) = n\left(\frac{1}{2^0}+\frac{1}{2^1}+...+\frac{1}{2^k}\right) = n\sum_{i=0}^{k} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^i = \left(2n-\frac{n}{2^k}\right) = 2n-1 \rightarrow \mathcal{O}(n)
$$

The time complexity of this loop is $\mathcal{O}(\log(n))$, so obviously I'm not understanding something correctly...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The things being added are not the values $i$ assumes, but whatever goes on inside the loop, which here is an $O(1)$ operation. There is also no reason why everything should be multiplied by $n$ outside.

Since the $O(1)$ operation happens $k$ times
$$T(n)=\sum_{i=0}^k1=k+1=O(\log n)$$

Comment: Ah okay! So the values `i` assumes are used to derive $k = \log(n)$ which answer the question "How many times does this loop run?". Using $k$ we then can calculate "whatever goes on inside the loop"?